# Laravel 5.4 Search query with join and pivot table

Tags: join, pivot-table, laravel-5.4

In my Laravel 5.4 project, I have 4 tables with many-to-many relationship as below:

```
tags
*******************
- id
- title

bloggers
*******************
- id
- name

posts
*******************
- id
- blogger_id
- title
- description

post_tag
*******************
- post_id
- tag_id
```

The search query works well with search by key words, but when I want to search by tag id, it doesn't work:

Please kindly help solve this problem.

Comment: Did you typo or something? `if(!empty($cate)) $q->wherePivot('tags.id', $tag);`, where is `$cate` come from?

Comment: It should be $tag not $cate.